# How to calculate "bounds" around a point with a distance for update camera. Google Maps IOS API

Tags: ios, google-maps, camera, maps, bounds

For my application, I want to calculate the "bounds" for an area around a central point. This area should be defined by a distance to the left and right, as well as top and bottom.

For example :

Central Location: 4.0000 - 44.0000

+/- 500m (right - left)

+/- 700m (top - bottom)

My question: how to calculate the bounds to apply the function:

GMSCameraPosition * camera = [mapView cameraForBounds: bounds insets: UIEdgeInsetsZero];

Thank you .

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution :

Formula:

```
φ2 = asin( sin φ1 ⋅ cos δ + cos φ1 ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos θ )

λ2 = λ1 + atan2( sin θ ⋅ sin δ ⋅ cos φ1, cos δ − sin φ1 ⋅ sin φ2 )
```

where   φ is latitude, λ is longitude, θ is the bearing (clockwise from north), δ is the angular distance d/R; d being the distance travelled, R the earth’s radius

JavaScript:(all angles in radians)

```
var φ2 = Math.asin( Math.sin(φ1)*Math.cos(d/R) +
                    Math.cos(φ1)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(brng) );
var λ2 = λ1 + Math.atan2(Math.sin(brng)*Math.sin(d/R)*Math.cos(φ1),
                         Math.cos(d/R)-Math.sin(φ1)*Math.sin(φ2));
```

The longitude can be normalised to −180…+180 using (lon+540)%360-180

from web site : http://www.movable-type.co.uk/scripts/latlong.html